# IBM Container deployment failure

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

Attempting to deploy a docker container to Bluemix. Installed the container service plugin, able to login to `api.ng.bluemix.net`, however when running `bluemix ic init` the following error is given:

```
{
    "code": "IC5097E", 
    "description": "Authentication was not successful: The container service has not been enabled for this org. Please login via \u2018bx login ...' + \u2018bx ic init ...' and try again.", 
    "environment": "prod-dal09", 
    "host_id": "144", 
    "incident_id": "1360-1497162332.121-675605", 
    "name": "InvalidToken", 
    "rc": "401", 
    "type": "Infrastructure"
}
FAILED
Your login state might have expired. Use 'bluemix login' to login again.
```

Any help toward helping maintain a valid token & successful deployment would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this [answer can help](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/364791/cannot-cf-login-on-stage1ngbluemixnet/):

> If you have a federated ID, you must log in to Bluemix by using an API key that you have to generate first.
>   Please [follow the instructions here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_troubleshoot.html#cs_federated_id?cm_sp=dw-bluemix-_-nospace-_-answers) and try logging in again with your API key

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming you have gone through the documentation of using IBM Bluemix with containers. I found their documentation here:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_adding_ov.html#container_images_adding_ov

it explains step by step instruction to follow. Just wondering if you missed any step.